# Laravel Rule that allows only alpha numeric with - (hiphen)

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

Here is my Rule for Taxi Code

```
'TaxiCode' =>  array('required'),
```

It should accept Alpha Numeric with Hiphen so i added

```
'TaxiCode' =>  array('required', 'regex:/^-/'),
```

When i add the alpha_num

```
'TaxiCode' =>  array('required', 'regex:/^-/', 'alpha_num'),
```

It shows the number is invalid

The input i given is

```
BMW - 1902
```

Comment: So it can also have spaces in it?

Comment: Yes , it can contain alphabet, numeric, space and hiphen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches only one hyphen. You can't combine `alpha_num` with `regex` *like that*.

Simply use a this regex and get rid of `alpha_num`:

```
'TaxiCode' =>  array('required', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+$/'),
```

(By the way, I'd keep the required because then you still get a nice error when nothing is filled in...)

Comment: Thanks, i included it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just regex:

```
'TaxiCode' => 'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-\s]+$/'
```